# Conditional where on stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure on **SQL Server** that take 3 parameters, all optional.
The parameters are `month`, `year`, and `class` (just a example).

If no value is informed to `month`, then the default value will be the current month, for `year`, the default value will be the current year.

Then in class, if no value is informed, the `where` conditional will not be used, or at least an `WHERE class IS NOT NULL` (all `class` must be returned).

The stored procedure run a select, according with the parameters.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_TEST]
    @month INT,
    @year INT,
    @class NVARCHAR(10) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF @month IS NULL
        SET @month = MONTH(GETDATE())

    IF @year IS NULL
        SET @year = YEAR(GETDATE())

    SELECT
        *
    FROM 
        TABLE_TEST V
    WHERE
        MONTH(V.DATE) = @month AND
        YEAR(V.DATE) = @year AND
        CLASS = ???
```

so, in `WHERE`, I tried the following codes:

Code 01:

```
WHERE
    MONTH(V.DATE) = @month AND
    YEAR(V.DATE) = @year AND
    (@class IS NOT NULL AND CLASS = @class)
```

Results:

- If I pass a value to `@class`, everything worked
- If I pass a `NULL` to `@class`, nothing is returned.

Code 02:

```
WHERE
    MONTH(V.DATE) = @month AND
    YEAR(V.DATE) = @year AND
    V.CLASS = CASE WHEN @class != NULL THEN @class END
```

Results:

- If I pass a value to `@class`, nothing is returned.
- If I pass a `NULL` to `@class`, nothing is returned.

How I'm calling the stored procedure:

With `NULL` on `class`:

```
EXEC [dbo].[SP_TEST]
    @month = NULL,
    @year = NULL,
    @class = NULL
```

With some `class`:

```
EXEC [dbo].[SP_TEST]
    @month = NULL,
    @year = NULL,
    @class = 'TEST_A'
```

Comment: 02) `@class != NULL` >>> `@class IS NULL` / `@class IS NOT NULL` 01) `@class IS NOT NULL AND CLASS = @class` - and if @class is NULL (which is your point) then what? You almost done it.

Comment: I update the 01 to `((@class IS NOT NULL AND V.CLASS = @class) OR (@class IS NULL))` and worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is this:

```
WHERE V.CLASS = ISNULL(@class, V.CLASS)
```

This means: Either `V.CLASS = @class` or (if `@class` is `null`) `V.CLASS = V.CLASS`, which is always true.

And by the way: Your query may not be performant, as the use of `MONTH` and `YEAR` does not allow indices to be used.

Instead, create the first of the month you want to return and the first of the following month:

```
DECLARE @monthStart DATETIME
DECLARE @monthEnd DATETIME
SET @monthStart = DATETIMEFROMPARTS
                  (
                    ISNULL(@year, YEAR(GETDATE())), 
                    ISNULL(@month, MONTH(GETDATE())), 
                    1, 
                    0,
                    0, 
                    0, 
                    0
                  )
SET @monthEnd = DATEADD(mm, 1, @monthStart)
```

My suggestion would be to calculate the first date and last date of the requested month for the year and then use

```
WHERE V.DATE >= @monthStart AND V.DATE < @monthEnd
```

Comment: tks! :D your code was clean, and the explanation was very good! and the extra information about month and year is great!

Answer (score 1):

Your code After WHERE CLOUSE SHOULD BE LIKE

```
WHERE
     MONTH(V.DATE) = @month AND
     YEAR(V.DATE) = @year AND
     @class IS NULL OR V.CLASS = @class
```

Comment: While this is also correct, single line answers that don't explain anything are discouraged. At least write a line or two about why that works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

WHERE
     MONTH(V.DATE) = @month AND
     YEAR(V.DATE) = @year AND

```
 class = case
 when class=@class then @class
 else table_name.class
```